# Comparing infinitesimal sequences

Tags: calculus

Why to compare two infinitesimal sequences we take the limit of their ratio ?

I don't understand the logic.

Comment: Can you give an example of one that you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand the sense of the definition. Why taking the limit of their ratio and not another formula ?

Comment: It isn't a sequence of infinitesimals, it is a sequence of reals converging to zero. That's very different.

Comment: I know that are sequences of reals converging to zero. But why to estabilish which is the faster we take the limit of their ratio and not another formula ?

Comment: What is an "infinitesimal sequence"?

Comment: A sequence whose limit is 0

Answer (score 8):

I assume you ask about sequences $\sigma$ that approach $0$.
What options do we have to compare such sequences?  Say

$\alpha:\ $ $a_1,a_2,\cdots\to0$ and
$\beta:\ $ $b_1,b_2,\cdots\to0$.

We could look at $a_n-b_n$ but that is very uninteresting, since 
$\lim_n(a_n-b_n)=\lim_n a_n - \lim_n b_n=0-0=0$.
So we would always get $0$, and it is not interesting if you always get the same answer.
It doesn't tell you anything, no information to tell how one such sequence is different from another.

If you take the ratio $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ then that is another matter. Then you get some variety in the answer and you may compare sequences in a more interesting way.

For example take $a_n=\frac1n$, $b_n=\frac1{2^n}$ and $c_n=\frac1{2^{n+3}}$, $n\ge1$.

$\alpha:\ $ $1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\frac15,\frac16,\frac17,\cdots\to0$

$\beta:\ $ $\frac12,\frac14,\frac18,\frac1{16},\frac1{32},\frac1{64},\frac1{128},\cdots\to0$ and

$\gamma:\ $ $\frac1{16},\frac1{32},\frac1{64},\frac1{128},\frac1{256},\frac1{512},\frac1{1024},\cdots\to0$  .

Note that $\lim_n\frac{b_n}{c_n}=8$ while $\lim_n\frac{b_n}{a_n}=0$ (one way to show the later is, to compute, first simplifying and the using L'Hospital rule, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac1{2^x}}{\frac1x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{2^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^x\ln2}=0$).
This time, as we will see (unlike when we would take $\lim_n(a_n-b_n)$ ) the case when the limit of the ratio is $0$ is the interesting case.

Indeed the case when the limit is a finite number, like $\lim_n\frac{b_n}{c_n}=8$, happens only when the two sequences are "about the same" (there is a precise mathematical term for that, that I will omit, perhaps someone could add a comment). In the example given above, the sequence $\gamma=\{c_n\}=\{\frac1{2^{n+3}}\}$ is obtained from the sequence $\beta=\{b_n\}=\{\frac1{2^n}\}$ when we drop the first three terms. Since the limit of a sequence does not change if we drop finitely many terms, we are inclined to consider sequences that are obtained from one another by dropping or adding finitely many terms to be "about the same sequence". This is (at least one) intuitive justification (perhaps one could also use the word logic) why we consider the case when the ratio approaches a finite non-zero number to be an indication that the sequences "approach $0$ at about the same rate". (More precisely, two sequences are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) if the ratio approaches $1$. I would call two sequences similar, if the ratio approaches a finite non-zero number, but I could not find a link to confirm if this terminology is accepted.)

On the other hand for the sequences $\alpha=\{\frac1n\}$ and $\beta=\{\frac1{2^n}\}$, even if one drops or adds finitely many terms to each sequence, the limit of the ratio will remain unchanged, $\lim_n\frac{b_n}{a_n}=0$. This singles out the case when $\lim_n\frac{b_n}{a_n}=0$ (this case tells us something about the behavior of the sequences as $n\to\infty$ regardless of what happens at the first finitely many terms). Since $b_n=a_n\cdot\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ we could see that not only the $b_n\to0$ but also the $b_n$ become "infinitely smaller" than the $a_n$ as $n\to\infty$. 
We could say that $b_n\to0$ "*much faster than*" $a_n\to0$.

Similar considerations apply not only to sequences, but also to functions. 
The case when  both functions (or sequences) approach $\infty$ is interesting in applications (then their reciprocals both approach $0$). The limit of the ratio turns out to be a handy and useful (as well as a simple) tool in defining when one function (or sequence) is faster, and this is the logic why we would want to consider it, instead of something else.

For more along the same ideas you may want to read about the [big O and little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).